# convert netbeans php project to war file to deploy in remote web server

Tags: php, netbeans, war

i have been searching for build and clean to convert the netbeans php project to a war file,after some searches i found that it is only for java project.So i have tried to configure the path var/www ,but it shows invalid path,can any one help me how can i convert a netbeans project to war file.I would like to test project on another system so how can i access the netbeans project in another computer to test its functionalities,i am stuck somebody help

thank you

Comment: did you look at this? http://www.examulator.com/moodle/mod/resource/view.php?id=457

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend you to used WAMP Server. Follow the steps below.

1. Cut your PHP project from Netbeans Projects and paste it on C:\wamp\www.
2. It assumed that you've already ran the WAMP Server. Go to netbeans, open your php project which is now already in C:\wamp\www directory.
3. Right-click your php project>properties>run configuration. You have to match the port number of your php project from your web server(WAMP Server). See httpd.conf if you want to change the port. By default, it listens to port 80.
4. Single-click your php project and hit f6.
5. Voila! :D

This is my way to run PHP project on NetBeans. Web Servers from NetBeans were only designed for JAVA Apps only. Web Server from WAMP is designed for PHP.

Hope it helps -_-